# Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider SqlServer, Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, ado.net, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-sql-database

My ASP project working perfect on localhost but When I deploy my asp project on Azure after changing the connection string I get this exception online **Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.**

I'm following this azure tutorial

> https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-webforms-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/

Please Help I'm having this issue previous week so kindly help me

Comment: I guess it could be a DLL that is missing?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the reference to your 'Data Provider' is added incorrectly. Try adding the Entity framework as [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework) package.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my data provide are given below

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my data provide are given below:     in web config  dbprovider tag i 'm using this  '<add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />'

Comment: I already installed above mention nuget pckages and locally everything is working fine but after deplying it gives me exception

Comment: I have also mention this provider but no vain please guide '<add name="SqlClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer" type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />'

Comment: Hari Hara Chandan please guide me i'm stuck here this is my roadblock